# exception thrown when an active record transaction is made from a thread in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am facing an issue while making active record transactions from a thread. When multiple requests are being made to the Rails application while this thread is running, an exception is being thrown.

The exception message I am getting is "prepare called on a closed database"

My code roughly looks like this:-

```
Thread.new do
  begin
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
     # some long running operations including some ActiveRecord operations 

    end
  rescue => e
      puts e.message
  end
end
```

The exception message indicates that the database is closed, but shouldn't my connection from the connection pool prevent the database from being closed?

Is there a way I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Issue resolved by adding config.threadsafe! in application.rb

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps mentioned in the below link.

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/450